# Installing apache kudu in docker in windows machine

Tags: apache-kudu

When installing apache kudu in docker by executing the below command set:

```
KUDU_QUICKSTART_IP=$(ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}' | tail -1)
```

I get below error:

```
tail: option used in invalid context -- 1
```

How to avoid this?